# What is the difference between calling function with parentheses and without in python?

Tags: python

I have a question. Lets assume that we have function hello(). What is the difference between calling it with parentheses and without? When I call hello() it is referring to an object with value equals this function. Or maybe am I wrong? What happens when I call it without parentheses?

I wonder why

```
def hello():
    pass

print(id(hello))
print(id(hello()))
```

returns different results

```
4400606744
4398942536
```

Comment: you can't "call" a function without parenthesis. `hello()` is a function call, `hello` is not. `hello` is just the function, not a call to it.

Comment: @ASMackay I have updated my question. It doesn't look like a duplicated question now, isn't it?

Comment: It's different because in the first case you're getting the `id` of the function object itself, and in the second you get the `id` of whatever the function returns (here: `None`).

Comment: @deceze, you are right. When I write `print(id(None))` I get the same number as `print(id(hello()))`.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: see https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html to get a better understanding of the difference between objects and the names used to refer to objects.

---

A function is called if and *only* if you use parentheses. `hello()` calls the function; `hello` is simply a *name* bound to the function, and can be used, for example, to pass the function object as an argument to another function.

```
def caller(f):
    f()

def hello():
    print("hi")

def goodbye():
    print("bye")

caller(hello)  # Prints "hi"
caller(goodbye)  # Prints "bye"
```

---

Regarding your update, `id` returns different values because each call to `id` receives a completely separate object as its argument. With `id(hello)`, `id` gets the function object itself. With `id(hello())`, `id` is getting the object *returned* by the call to `hello`; it's the same as

```
x = hello()
print(id(x))
```

Comment: I assume that hello() is a variable referring to an object with value equals this function?

Comment: @Wahtdbogh Everything in python is an object and so is the function you mentioned.

Comment: Okey, but hello is also a variable referring to the object with value equals this function?

Comment: @Wahtdbogh the parentheses in this case are an operator, in the same way that unary negation is an operator: `hello` is to `hello()` as `x` is to `-x`. Hello is the variable which stores the function, the parenthesis mean that you want to attempt to call the object stored in that variable as a function.

Comment: @Wahtdbogh If at all that's a very backwards way of putting it. `hello` is a variable referring to the function. `hello()` calls it and returns whatever the function returns.

Comment: but if hello() calls it we can name it a variable, isn't it?

Comment: @Wahtdbogh Be more precise about what you're referring to with "it".

Comment: Yes, `hello` is a name for the anonymous `function` object defined by the `def` statement. If you were to write `foo = hello`, then both `foo()` and `hello()` would call the same underlying function. Similary, if you wrote `hello = 3`, you would lose that reference to the function; `hello` now refers to the integer `3` and `hello()` would produce a type error, since `int` objects are not callable. See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html for a better understanding of the relationship between names and objects.

Comment: ***No***. `hello` refers to a function object; `hello()` is an expression that is evaluated by  *calling* the function; the value of the expression is the return value of the function call.

Comment: So hello() is neither object, nor a variable, nor a value?

Comment: No, but it is an expression that, like any other expression, *has* a value. Just like `3 + 5` is not an object, variable, or value, but has as its value the integer `8`.

Comment: So hello() should be called `expression` or does it have a name?

Comment: It is a function call expression.

Comment: So `hello` is neither object, nor a variable, nor a value?

Comment: Read the link I posted at the top of the answer. I'm not answering any more questions in the comments.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR**: the parentheses execute the function itself; without them you treat the function as it were a variable

In python you append the parentheses (with optional variables inside) to the function name *only* when you want to **invoke** it.

But there is also another way to use function names.
In fact, in python functions are first class objects, that means that the function can be passed around as if it where a variable name. To do you must not append the parentheses () at the end of the function name.

Check the following:

```
def f():
    return 'f'

print( type(f) ) # result: <class 'function'>
print( type(f()) ) # result: <class 'str'>
```

As you can see, in the first instance we print the type of f (without parentheses), which is a *function*

In the second instance we print the type of f() (with the parentheses), which is a *string*, that is the type returned by f when it is invoked.

This behavior is useful to pass functions as parameters of other functions, etc, etc.

The fact that id() and id(function-invoked>) returns different ids:

```
print(id(hello))   # here it returns the id of the function name

print(id(hello())) # here it returns the id 
                   # of the object returned by the function itself
```

Answer (score 2):

**In short**, function with parenthesis `()` is actually calling (invoke) that function *whereas* function without parenthesis `()` is an object of that function which can be passed as an argument and later be called by appending `()` to it.

```
def hello():
    return 1
```

i.e.
`hello` >> returns object
`hello()` >> outputs 1

Answer (score 1):

hello refers to the function object, hello() calls the function itself.

For example:

```
>>> def hello():
...     print "hello"
... 
>>> hello
<function hello at 0x106c91398>
>>> hello()
hello
```

Comment: I assume that hello() is a variable referring to an object with value equals this function?

Comment: When you issue hello, Python is showing you the representation of the function. hello() invokes the function. The parentheses contain the arguments supplied to the function when you invoke it. In this example, hello() takes no arguments.

EDIT: Removed weasel word "usually". The parentheses always contain the arguments supplied :)

Comment: Okay, but when I have for instance variable `a=2` then variable `a` is referring to object with value equals `2`. When I print `a` it returns `2` Accordingly in this case `hello` is a variable referring to object with value equals function. So when I print `hello` it should returns string "hello", not address of this function.

Comment: When you print hello, you see the address in memory the expression is held in. When you **invoke** hello(), you see the output of calling the function. When you print hello, you are not **invoking** the function.

Answer (score 1):

A function is an object just like any other object in Python. If you define a new function, a new function object is created and is assigned to the name of the function.

```
def spam():
    print('The knights who say Ni!')

print(spam) # => <function spam at 0x7fc64efc6f28>

spam() # => output: 'The knights who say Ni!
```

As you can see after the function was defined it got assigned to the name of `spam`. It is essentially similar to an assignment statement being run. Now that name is going to give you **access** to the function but in order to actually use it you have to **call** it using the parentheses like `spam()`. If you don't call it using the parentheses, it will just return the function object that has been assigned to the name `spam`.