# AttributeError: 'RandomForestClassifier' object has no attribute 'estimators_'

Tags: python

```
scores=[]
for model_name,mp in  model_param.items():
    model_selction=GridSearchCV(estimator=mp['model'],param_grid=mp['model'],cv=5,return_train_score=False)
    model_selction.fit(X,y)
    scores.append({
        'model':model_name,
        'best_score':model_selction.best_score_,
        'best_params':model_selction.best_param_
    })
```

Comment: can you explain where the error occurs instead of dumping the code

Comment: I suspect you did not call the method, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46001292/what-is-the-difference-between-calling-function-with-parentheses-and-without-in